# Software for mood boards?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, software-recommendation

What software do you use for making moodboards? Is Illustrator the best option? Has anyone got any other methods or ideas about making moodboards? Specifically from found digital images and photography.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion would be to go with **the program you are the most comfortable**, be it Illustrator, Photoshop, Gimp or any graphics software that lets you paste images and add comments.

**Illustrator** is a really good choice, you'll find it easy to add and modify elements.

This article could be of great help, especially regarding images:

- [**24 pro tips for creating inspirational mood boards**](http://www.creativebloq.com/graphic-design/mood-boards-812470)

> When putting together mood boards, think of yourself as a curator
>   rather than a collector, and try to have meaning and threads from one
>   image to the next. It makes for easier interpretation.

And:

> An **offline** mood board will generally be looser in style and require
>   the extra kick and emotive spark that comes from it being presented to
>   a client. An **online** mood board should be tighter and will generally
>   need to work harder to convey a theme or style.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are 2 distinct steps in designing a mood board:

1. Form/style of the mood board: freeform or tight pattern, what type of images, [soft or bright colors](http://www.surveycrest.com/blog/6-revealing-facts-about-color-psychology/), [fonts](http://marketingland.com/everything-need-know-fonts-conversion-optimization-100113) - these factors are determined by what the mood board is for.
2. Once you have decided on a style, you need to come up with a way to put everything together - a software to do the mood board.

Since you have asked for software I would focus on that part only. You can use Photoshop, Illustrator, Gimp - they are standards in design process.

If your focus is to [**quickly setup your mood board**](http://www.turbocollage.com/mood-board.html) then I would highly recommend [TurboCollage](http://www.turbocollage.com).

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply creating a montage of image grabs and a few typographical and dropped ilustrator design elements I find InDesign is far better as you can drop a vast quantity of items down to multiple pages very quickly then arrange from there, multiple pages are also much simpler in Indesign to export as a PDF document for presentation or to send to print.

If you want a single moodboard with editable design element workings and so on Illustrator is better.